# Can't decorate third party read-only function, how to wrap it for additional functionality?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wrapper, pyodbc, python-decorators

I have the following (heavily simplified) decorator:

```
def log_and_execute(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(*args, **kwargs)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

I want to use this to decorate `pyodbc.connect.cursor`.

Since I obviously can't edit the source code to do it, I'm trying to do it like this:

```
import pyodbc

connection = pyodbc.connect("connection_string_here")
cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute = log_and_execute(cursor.execute)
```

But I get the following error:

> ```
> AttributeError: 'pyodbc.Cursor' object attribute 'execute' is read-only
> ```

How should I do this, so that I don't have to change all of my already existing `cursor.execute` calls?

Comment: You can't. Why not create a wrapper object that just proxies to a cursor stored as an attribute?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm not sure what you mean by your solution. I'm trying to do this so that I don't have to change all of my existing `cursor.execute` calls.

Comment: The `Cursor` class used in `pyodbc` is coded entirely in C, and can't be monkeypatched. Your only option would be to create your own class that uses `__getattr__` and a few more `__dunder__` special methods to proxy calls to the wrapped cursor instance (you need additional special methods to support the iteration and context manager support that pyodbc cursors implement). The `__getattr__` method just grabs the same attribute from the cursor instance and returns it. That's the point you can then apply extra wrapping too, like printing.

Comment: @MartijnPieters would you want to expand your comment to an answer, which shows an example class which does this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't alter the pyodbc `Cursor` class, it is written in C and doesn't allow for setting attributes.

At best you can write a wrapper class:

```
class CursorWrapper:
    def __init__(self, cursor):
        self.cursor = cursor

    def execute(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(*args, **kwargs)
        return self.cursor.execute(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.cursor, attr)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.cursor)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.cursor.__enter__()

    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.cursor.__exit__(*args, **kwargs)
```

then wrap your cursor in that class each time:

```
cursor = CursorWrapper(connection.cursor())
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is a great solution!